# Series question, telescoping.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Okay i'm starting to get a handle on this. my new question is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{n(n + 3)}.$$

I know i have to use Partial Fraction Decomposition, and what i came up with is 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{n+3}).$$

Am I on the correct track? It doesn't seem to be working out correctly.

Comment: Possibly related is one of my favorite formulas: $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+m)} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k(k+n)}$. If you know this you can use it on $m=3$ and let $n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost, but
$$
\frac3{n(n+3)}=\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+3}
$$

Comment: Ahh! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tibbiticus: You're welcome. Were you able to compute the sum?